# Can more then one process share their heap memory?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, malloc

From what i know, threads do share the heap memory, but can different processes share one heap also, does it happens by default?

If not, when one uses malloc ,and untill the heap memory runs out ,does the malloc operation is just returning the next memory block in the heap? because its clearly not allocated becase only one process has access to the heap, 
for example, lets say the heap memory holds 1-10 adresses,
first malloc call (for 3 bytes) does not need to search any free memory it just allocates 1-3 adresses and returns adress 1, now second call also doesnt need to look for free space its just returning adress 4, and so on..
so until the memory run out malloc just returnes the adress of the next block of memory it doesn't need to look for free unallocated memory.

Is that trully what is happening?

Comment: I suggest that you specify what platform you are asking about.

Comment: Too long to be copied in an SO answer, but [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation#Implementations) gives some explanation on different malloc implementations - BTW the C standard does **not** specify malloc implementation...

Comment: You're asking two questions. The first one is about shared memory, and the second one is about the behavior of `malloc` (which cannot be accurately answered until you tell us which implementation you are referring to ;-)). Please split your questions into separate threads.

Comment: @MartinTörnwall: on old MS/DOS and Win16 implementations, the global heap was actually shared among multiple processes, which could give sense to this question

Comment: @Serge Ballesta You just didn't understand the question.

Comment: Allocation is just an implementation detail, and the wikipedia page I linked should give you enough explainations about real implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Each process has a unique memory map (virtual to physical memory map). So the same address in two different processes will normally hit different physical memory. Exception from these exists, when you have mapped memory specifically to be shared, etc.

Comment: and what about the allocation ?

Comment: Allocation usually happens by either calling mmap on annomyous memory or by adjusting sbrk(). Both will result in more memory beeing mapped into the process. This memory will be uniqe for this process